# How to display image from Uint8list websocket flutter (live camera device)?

Tags: flutter, image, video, websocket, stream

How to know what inside Uint8list?

I have a websocket severt it stream live video or image from traffic camera . but i dont know how to display it on flutter. when i using image.memory it have an error invalid image https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAmEn.png.

it my respones from sever.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr0Fd.png.

output respones when i print it on flutter [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ioOw.png)

Comment: You need to enter the image descriptions - do you expect people to click the images and see what you meant?

Comment: sorry, but i can not add image ,i dont have Reputation 10 to post images